# Meaning of "anticipated cosmetic collapse" in Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow

Tags: meaning, andrews-brain, e-l-doctorow

In Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow:

> There were a lot of western blondes at the college but mostly of the
> blaringly self-indicative kind, with  an empty-headedness or cunning
> about them, or perhaps their faces too clearly **anticipated cosmetic
> collapse**. Briony was fine-featured, her looks were modestly
> aristocratic, you would think she belonged at a country house in the
> Cotswolds or perhaps in a Polish shtetl.

What does he mean by "anticipated cosmetic collapse"?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that this refers to women who use excessive amounts of makeup. I've no particular support for this other than my own reading of the sentence, but here's my reasoning.

Apologies in advance that this answer is going to sound very sexist. My presumption is that the narrator of the novel is, too, so there's not really any way around it in exploring their thoughts.

Consider first the context of the statement. The sentence as a whole is clearly referring to different kinds of women who are, for various reasons, unattractive to the narrator. They are "empty-headed" or "cunning". So it makes sense that "cosmetic collapse" should also be read as an indicator of unattractiveness. You can also gauge this from the following sentence about how "fine-featured" Briony is by contrast. The preceding sentence is clearly setting up a juxtaposition between Briony and the other college girls.

Within this context, we can infer that "cosmetic" might well refer to "cosmetics" as another word for makeup, a sense that's reinforced by the fact that it's their "faces" that are going to collapse. Given that makeup is generally seen by society as increasing a woman's attractiveness, though, there must be something else here since we're talking about things that are unattractive to the narrator, a fact made clear by the word "collapse": something is going to go wrong.

So my reading of it is that the women are using makeup to cover up otherwise plain or unattractive features, or (less likely) that are using so much makeup that they appear overworked and unappealing. So the full sense of the phrase is that the narrator is "anticipating" something will go wrong - "collapse" - with the makeup and that they, too, will be rendered unattractive to the narrator.

Comment: I can imagine moisturisers delaying "cosmetic collapse" but not ordinary make up. But maybe the narrator doesn't understand the difference.

Comment: @Tsundoku perhaps I've not explained it very well. I think what this is saying is that it's more of a case of when the makeup comes off - "collapses" - the results underneath won't be very appealing.

Answer (score 1):

I think he means that in the future, they will age and be less attractive, i.e. they have the beauty of youth that will soon fade (cosmetic meaning 'relating to appearance'). I am not quite sure who anticipates the collapse, whether it is just the author, or the women themselves. I think it is the women because it is **their** faces that anticipate.

Throwing a whole lot of cultural subtext into my interpretation (which maybe I shouldn't), I think he is saying that they know they need to make the most of their looks while they can (presumably to get a husband). It could refer to the unlovely stereotype of women going to college to get a [Mrs. degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRS_Degree). This also relates back to the 'cunning' he sees in their faces (what do they have to be cunning about) and to 'empty-headed' (they are not here to study).

I haven't read the book, and I might be way off base here.